# Wooden fruit crates as edging for lawn

Tags: grass, raised-beds, border

As you can see, this grave needs some sort of edging to prevent soil from running down. Now i could use bricks for the job but that would take away the raised bed look of the grave that i like. Plus something slimmer would not only prevent the soil from sliding down and creating a mess on both sides, it would also allow me to have just enough space to plant some ground covers on both sides of the edge. I understand that metal edging would be the best option but that stuff isn't available in my city so i was thinking pulling apart wodden crates and using that. Would it work?[image]

Answer (score 1):

It will probably work in the short term, but the problems are

1. Crates like this are usually made from poor quality wood which soon rots.
2. To prevent rotting or insect damage in hot climates, the wood may have been treated with chemicals that harm plants.
3. The pieces of wood may be small, so the finished structure may look untidy because of all the joints.
4. The crates are usually made using nails that are designed so that they won't work loose when the crate is being used, and it is hard to remove them without damaging the wood.

In the UK, it would certainly be better to buy some timber [like this](https://www.wickes.co.uk/Products/Gardens/Garden-Decor/Garden-Sleepers+Raised-Bed-Kits/c/1000733?q=%3Aprice-asc%3AType%3AGarden+Sleepers&text=&Garden+Sleepers=Garden+Sleepers) which is intended to be used in permanent contact with soil outdoors and should last at least 5 to 10 years. That type of product might not be available where you live, of course.

Metal edging would be much more expensive than timber, and not really necessary unless you want it to last a very long time with no maintenance.